# Two Overlapping divisions, but upper one is unscrollable

Tags: css

I have two divisions in my html page with their respective css

```
<html>
<head>
#lowerone
{position:absolute; bottom:25px; right:25px; height:300px; width:300px;}
#upperone
{position:absolute; bottom:25px; right:25px; height:300px; width:300px; overflow:scroll;}
</head>
<body>
<div id="lowerone">
</div>
<div id="upperone">
<img src="/bg.3.jpg" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

But the upper div i.e. the UPPERONE is unscrollabe..
How to make it scrollable?

Answer (score 1):

Any specific reason of using 2 absolute positioned div overlapped on one another? and more over `<style>` tags are missing...And scroll works for me..

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kLCmc/)

Comment: the #upperone div is containing a image (as i given it in the code..)

Comment: I agree with Mr Alien ... the `#upperone` div is scrollable

Answer (score 0):

Check below code both scroll works ,

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
#lowerone
{position:absolute; bottom:25px; right:25px; height:250px; width:300px;overflow:scroll;}
#upperone
{position:absolute; bottom:25px; left:25px; height:250px; width:300px; overflow:scroll;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="lowerone">
    <img src="http://media.caranddriver.com/images/12q4/477956/2014-gmc-sierra-1500-photos-and-info-news-car-and-driver-photo-492039-s-450x274-1.jpg" />
</div>
<div id="upperone">
<img src="http://media.caranddriver.com/images/12q4/477956/2014-gmc-sierra-1500-photos-and-info-news-car-and-driver-photo-492039-s-450x274-1.jpg" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

### Here is my [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hiteshbhilai2010/kLCmc/10/)

Comment: if you need something different let me know , your question is not clear

Comment: Thanks but i asked the question in 2012.. :P

Comment: :P he he ;) oh did not notice that